# I need super privileges to ON event_sheduler

Tags: php, mysql

**I want to create event which delete my data from daily log column of table activity.**

- I have `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;` in my local server.
- But my main website is hosted at free hosting server.

**When I write `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`**

- It gives me mysql error of not having Super privileges.

**How can I do my task i.e deletion of data after 
every 1 day at 00:00 with having super privileges.**

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to execute certain commands like deletion of logs at specific time of day, you could create a `**cron job**` for the same and execute your command in the cron script.